# How do you stop bundler from showing pasword on screen when using capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, bundler

I have a question regarding capistano and bundler.

When I deploy my app via ssh copy, bundler asks me for my root password.  This is fine because I'm installing my gems to a seperate directory on the system.  However, when I type my password it shows up on the screen when I type it.  How do I get this to stop?

I'm using current stable versions of Rails, Bundler, Capistano.  System is running FreeBSD 9.0, Apache and Phusion Passenger.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way we do it is to useforwarding, and then capistrano will use your ssh key to get into the server.

```
ssh_options[:username] = 'USERNAME'
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
```

this way, you don't have to use passwords.  You just have to have your key in the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file, and configure your server to do forwarding.  Some Googling should yield steps on how to set up forwarding on your OS, but if it's Ubuntu, the [ubuntu ssh documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring) is a good place to start